# Cómo hacer mi primer programa simple con html y javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

Hola estoy iniciando con javascript y aún no entiendo mucho...  Quiero hacer un simple prgrama que haga el siguiente cálculo con información de un formulario de html:

[image: Tabla excel de ejemplo]

Lo que quiero que haga el formulario es solicitar los v1 y mostrarme el resultado (Suma de totales) al hacer click en el botón

```js
    <script>
        
            function calcularMm() {
                var hg = document.getElementById('hg').value;
                var hm = document.getElementById('hm').value;
                var resultado = (hg*170) + (hm*85);
                return = resultado;
            }
    
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AMASA ARTESANAL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    

    
</head>

<body>
   <h1 class="titulo">Calculo de Masa Madre</h1> 
    
    <fieldset class="cal_mm">
        
        <legend>Ingresa la cantidad de pedidos</legend>
        <form>
            <input style= width:50px type="text" id="hg"> Hogaza(s) Grande(s)<br><br>
            <input style= width:50px type="text" id="hm"> Hogaza(s) Mediana(s)<br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="calcularMm()" value="CALCULAR"><br><br>
            <p id="total"></p> gr de MM
        </form>
   
    </fieldset>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `innerHTML` para actualizar el contenido de tu elemento con id `total`, así:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>AMASA ARTESANAL</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        

        
    </head>

    <body>
       <h1 class="titulo">Calculo de Masa Madre</h1> 
        
        <fieldset class="cal_mm">
            
            <legend>Ingresa la cantidad de pedidos</legend>
            <form>
                <input style= width:50px type="text" id="hg"> Hogaza(s) Grande(s)<br><br>
                <input style= width:50px type="text" id="hm"> Hogaza(s) Mediana(s)<br><br>
                <input type="button" onclick="calcularMm()" value="CALCULAR"><br><br>
                <p id="total"></p> gr de MM
            </form>
       
        </fieldset>

        <script>
    
            function calcularMm() {
                var hg = document.getElementById('hg').value;
                var hm = document.getElementById('hm').value;
                var resultado = (hg*170) + (hm*85);
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = resultado;
            }
        
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```